# Redshift table uses 75GB of disk while the equivalent table on Mysql uses 40GB

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

The below query returns 75GB on redshift while on mysql the equivalent query returns 40GB.
`select size from svv_table_info where "table"='table_name'`

I always assumed redshift saves on disk space by sorting and distributing data in blocks and not having indexes.

What may be the reason for the differences that i missed?
I checked that :

1. there are no missing rows or columns on Mysql
2. Redshift table is vacuumed regularly

Comment: How many slices do you have in the cluster, and how many columns are in the table, and how many rows are in the table?